# Macros vs subroutines in assembly

Tags: assembly, macros

Statement: A subroutine cannot always be used to replace a macro in an assembly language program.

Is the above statement true or false?

My book has given false as an answer. But I cannot think of any scenario where Macro is possible but not subroutine. Can you please tell any hint if such a scenario is possible?

Comment: Hint: Recursion.

Comment: @Pseudonym Recursion is an example in the other direction.

Comment: This depends on the *assembler*, not the *assembly* language itself. Macros are usually *meta-code*, they can output *source code* while routines are just a logical grouping of instructions. Macros don't necessarily end up generating instructions. BTW, if the answer is false, should it imply that a subroutine can always replace a macro? This makes sense only in assembler with limited macro support.

Comment: @Pseudonym  You can of course recursively call a macro.  A call is just a jump that saves a return address.  There is nothing that prevents you from calling a chunk of code inside a macro.  Doesn't make a lot of sense though.

Comment: when you don't have a stack (or not yet initialized), or don't want to use it, or when you use things on the stack, and remove it while execution, like remove a variable amount of stack items ( the function would have to be different than the macro is )

Comment: Whoops, sorry, misunderstood the question.